# How to find all instances of two digits after ">" or "<" for a particular variable but not for other variables

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

In my sample, all ages are between `10` and `99`. I want to find all instances of the variable "age" being `>` or `<` than exactly two digits. I need to know the equality sign and the two digits. I do not want the equality sign and the two digits if they correspond to a different variable (e.g., height or weight). For simplicity, all ages, heights, and weights are exactly two digits. There are no units.

```
sample_text = "age > 10 but can be > 20 or > 22 - if the height is > 60 then age can be > 30, otherwise it must be < 35"
```

The output I am seeking is an `age_list` that looks like `[(">", "10"), (">", "20"), (">", "22"), (">", "30"), ("<", "35)]`. The list should be able to be of any length.

It is easy enough to get them all when the format is always "age" followed by sign followed by digits. I used the code below and it pulls out `[(">", "10"), (">", "30")]`, but I can't get the other digits - e.g., the `20` and `22` that are clearly tied to age. I need to get those but avoid the `60` tied to height (and any digit tied to weight if there is weight).

```
re.findall("age\s*[a-zA-Z\s]*(>|<)\s*(\d\d)", sample_text)
```

I have workarounds using `re.search` when the format is "age sign digit or something something sign digit", but the work arounds fail if there are a bunch of signs and digits that don't have "age" before them - e.g., "the age must be > 20 or if this then > 24 or also > 30 if that..."

Comment: Are "age", "height", and "weight" the only possible variables?

Comment: In this example yes. I can imagine other projects where there are many more complicating variables (i.e., variables where I don't want to capture the digits). But I hope/think that the same principles will apply.

Comment: Ok, that's definitely helpful! But if you need to cover things like "the age must be > 20 or if this then > 24", I don't think a regex is going to pull it off. You'd need a full natural language processing/understanding pipeline..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first temper the match to start at age, and do not cross matching either `height` or `width`

```
\bage(?:(?:(?!\b(?:height|weight)\b)[^<>])*[<>]\s+\d+)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bage` Match `age` preceded by a word boundary
- `(?:` Outer non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `(?:` Inner non capture group to repeat as a whole

    - `(?!\b(?:height|weight)\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not `height` or `weight` directly to the right and use a word boundary to prevent a partial match
    - `[^<>]` Match any char except `<` or `>`
  - `)*` Close inner non capture group and optionally repeat
  - `[<>]\s+\d+` Match either `<` or `>` then 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `)+` Close outer group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6iomV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vlXvt5)

The process the matches with re.findall and `([<>])\s+(\d+)` using 2 capture groups, capturing the sign in group 1 and the digits in group 2

```
import re

pattern = r"\bage(?:(?:(?!\b(?:height|weight)\b)[^<>])*[<>]\s+\d+)+"
s = ("age > 10 but can be > 20 or > 22 - if the height is > 60 then age can be > 30, otherwise it must be < 35\n")

for m in re.findall(pattern, s):
    print(re.findall(r"([<>])\s+(\d+)", m))
```

Output

```
[('>', '10'), ('>', '20'), ('>', '22')]
[('>', '30'), ('<', '35')]
```

Comment: Very helpful thx. A lot to study here. I see the \b requires that the extracted text begin with age. I also see the negative lookahead to avoid height|weight. Is the "[^<>]" saying avoid text where < or > follows height or weight? I need to study that and the nested uncaptured groups (with "?:").

Comment: @vintagedeek the `\b` is a word boundary and the `[^<>]` a negated character class. I am not behind my machine right now, but I will add an explanation later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import re
sample_text = "age > 10 but can be > 20 or > 22 - if the height is > 60 then age can be > 30, otherwise it must be < 35"
matched = re.findall(r'[<>]|[\d]+', sample_text)
results = []
for i in range(0, len(matched) - 1, 2):
    results.append((matched[i], matched[i+1]))
print(results)
# output: [('>', '10'), ('>', '20'), ('>', '22'), ('>', '60'), ('>', '30'), ('<', '35')]
```